# Compare integrations of two functions

Tags: calculus, analysis

Given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, both of them are continuous under a closed interval [a,b]. For any value c $\in$ [a,b], $f(c)<g(c)$. Does $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx < \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx $ hold? and why does it hold?

Comment: Certainly the inequality holds. The main issue is what properties of the (Riemann?) integral we are allowed to take as having been proved.

Comment: Are both of the functions positive on $[a,b]$? What do you mean by "under" a closed interval? Are they negative for all $x \in [a,b]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. To see this, $h(x):=g(x)-f(x)>0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Additionally, $h(x)$ is continuous since $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are continuous. It follows that $\int_a^b h(x)dx>0$, so 
$$0>\int_a^b h(x) dx = \int_a^b (g(x)-f(x))dx = \int_a^b g(x)dx - \int_a^b f(x)dx.$$
Thus $\int_a^b f(x)dx< \int_a^b g(x)dx$.

To see why $\int_a^b h(x)>0$: given $c \in (a,b)$, $h(c)>0$. Since $h(x)$ is continuous, there exists an interval $I\subseteq[a,b]$ of positive width $L$ containing $c$ such that $h(x) > \frac{h(c)}{2}$ on $I$. Then $\int_I h(x) dx \geq \frac{h(c)}{2} \cdot L >0$. Thus $\int_a^b h(x) dx \geq \int_I h(x)dx >0$.